# C++ shader, HLSL , how to send to the shader , the texture? "sampler2d"?

Tags: c++, directx, textures, shader, hlsl

im starting learning some Shader manipulation witg C++ and HLSL, im using **D3DXCompileShaderFromFile** to do some tests while am learning

i was able to compile and run some VertexShader and PixelShader, send some Attributes, like 
float, float2, float3, float4 , float4x4 , to set worldMatrix ,Color information ,etc, here is some example:

```
void CShader::SetVector4(char name[], Vect4f vect)
{
D3DXVECTOR4 v(vect.x,vect.y,vect.z,vect.w);
D3DXHANDLE h = m_pConstantTable->GetConstantByName(NULL, name);
m_pConstantTable->SetVector(m_pDevice, h, &v);
}
```

almost the same thing with SetMatrix and SetFloat, ex:

```
myShader->SetVector4("Diffuse",Vect4f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f) );
```

but i ran to a problem doing so Basic Light shader

how can i send a texture to my "pixelShader"? in my ps is declared as "sampler2d" type, so im not sure what to use to send this information

```
float4  Diffuse;
float4  Ambient;
sampler2D baseMap;


float4 Main(float3 L: TEXCOORD0, float3 N: TEXCOORD1,float2 texCoord: TEXCOORD2 ) : COLOR
{
  float facingRatio =  dot(L, N);
  float4 tex = tex2D( baseMap, texCoord );

  return tex * Diffuse * facingRatio + Ambient * tex;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you just need to bind the texture as normal?  Not familiar with the directx api as I normally use Ogre, but quick look up suggests [SetTexture(sampler, texture)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174461%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the way to go, with sampler being the sampler register.
You can explicitly say which register the texture uses in the shader if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pete!, i took a quick look on SetTexture(sampler, texture) documentation like you said, and i was able to figure out what to do, i made  this new setter

```
void CShader::SetTexture(char name[])
{
    IDirect3DBaseTexture9* texture = NULL;
    D3DXHANDLE h = m_pConstantTable->GetConstantByName(NULL, name);

    int tex_idx = m_pConstantTable->GetSamplerIndex(h);

    m_pDevice->SetTexture(tex_idx, texture);    
    m_pDevice->SetSamplerState(tex_idx, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
    m_pDevice->SetSamplerState(tex_idx, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
    m_pDevice->SetSamplerState(tex_idx, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
}
```

ex:

```
myShader->SetTexture("baseMap");
```

and somehow, it works, im not quite sure why , because i send to the "SetTexture" property an empty "texture"

Comment: Looks reasonable apart from the NULL texture.  If it is actually getting the texture you want then you must be sending it to the GPU elsewhere and it is some sort of fluke.